# In firefox, back, tab close, new tab icon is not shown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

I have downloaded firefox 19 tar file and extracted it. Executing firefox opens firefox without icons like close, new tab etc. as shown in figure (OS: ubuntu). Is there any step am I missing? In their [help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) it is said as just extracting and executing it enough.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The new tab icon is the button on the right just next to your single opened tab. There is no close button because you only have one tab open. It will appear when you open more tabs.

[image]

---

To add the navigation toolbar do this:

[image]

---

I am not sure if the close tab button is there in the vanilla firefox. I get it by using the [Tab Mix Plus add-on.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/).

Comment: Nope eventhough opening more than one tab, there is no close icon. Updated the image with two tabs. Also see back button also missing

Comment: @BalajiSivanath see updated answer.